# jqgrid set method in the API

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

if a get method call is like this

```
jQuery('#list6').jqGrid('getGridParam','records')
```

then set method could be this way ?

```
 jQuery('#projectList').jqGrid('setGridParam','records',6);
```

I want to set records in the jqgrid, but I can't find a API.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Correct form of usage of `setGridParam` is like

```
jQuery('#projectList').jqGrid('setGridParam', {records: 6}); // STILL WRONG!!!
```

but you can't set *readonly* properties of jqGrid in the way. You can see in the column "Can be changed?" of the table on [the page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) of the documentation which options of jqGrid you can change and which not.

I am sure that you try to go in the wrong way. So the problem which you try to solve should never exist at all.